# Policy in azure is non complaint for encryption in unattached disk

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-policy

The policy is showing as non compliant for encryption of the unattached disk in azure.
The unattached disk is default encrypted. How to sort it. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is the non-compliance reason? What alias are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're only using the managed disk encryption, but don't use the Bitlocker/ADE encryption.

From the Security center warning:

> Encrypt your Windows and Linux virtual machines' disks using Azure Disk Encryption (ADE).
> ADE provides OS and data disk encryption to protect your data and help meet your organizational and compliance commitments.
> ADE uses Windows' industry-standard BitLocker Device Encryption and Linux's DM-Crypt system.
> Use ADE if your compliance or security requirements require end-to-end encryption of your data and ephemeral (locally attached temporary) disk.

> Alternatively, by default, Managed Disks are encrypted at rest by default using Azure Storage Service
> Encryption where the encryption keys are Microsoft managed keys in Azure. If this meets your compliance and security requirements,
> you can leverage the default managed disk encryption to meet your requirements.